# Silverlight ScaleTransform issue

Tags: silverlight, scaletransform

I am working silvelight application and I phasing issue of layout I mean I have I WrapPanel and this will be adjust according to scaletransform widght and height,
and now I adding WrapPannel Children is Image so problem is adjustment of width and height.

Image will render actual size of the wrappanel so the my control would not render in a proper location so i am trying to solve this proble using the ScaleTransform, but this would not working properly,.

actually what happen the image could be render in the actual size of the Wrappanel so  the Wrappanel could be adjusted according to the ScaleTransform so the i am not able to render properly children.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but I find it difficult to understand your exact issue. If I do uderstand, have you considered placing the image in a ViewBox control?

Comment: Ok but how I can Autoadjust no fo images into the size I mean how I can Wrap the no of images.

Comment: Could you post some code so I can see what you see? It might help to have the XAML.